# VBA: Code not running after ToggleFormsDesign

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the following code in VBA (MS Word), that is meant to run after I click in a button, named *cmdFormPreencher* inserted in my Document:

```
Private Sub cmdFormPreencher_Click()
'
If ActiveDocument.FormsDesign = False Then
    ActiveDocument.ToggleFormsDesign
End If
'
ThisDocument.cmdFormPreencher.Select
ThisDocument.cmdFormPreencher.Delete

ActiveDocument.ToggleFormsDesign

'
UserForm2.Show
End Sub
```

The purpose of the code above is to delete that button inserted in my document.
But when I run the code only the button is selected. When I tried to figure out what is happening by debugging, it showed me the code runs until `ActiveDocument.ToggleFormsDesign` and not running the code remaining

Is this a bug of VBA, or am I doing something wrong? If so, how can I get around this problem?

Thanks!

**Note**: The ActiveX button is not in Header and Footer. The Text Wrap is set to *In Front of Text*

**Edit:**

When I try to run a macro, activating FormDesign, Selecting the ActiveX button and then deleting, I get this code:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
'
    ActiveDocument.ToggleFormsDesign
    ActiveDocument.Shapes("Control 52").Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.Delete
    ActiveDocument.ToggleFormsDesign
End Sub
```

But when I run this code nothing happens...

Comment: You have `ActiveDocument.ToggleFormsDesign` twice here... does the code stop after the first one, skipping `ThisDocument.cmdFormPreencher.Select` and `.Delete`, or does it stop after the second one, skipping `UserForm2.Show`?

Comment: @Mat'sMug After the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. When an Office application is in Design Mode code should not run on an ActiveX object that's part of the document.

I take it this is an ActiveX button and in that case, it's a member of the InlineShapes or Shapes collection - Word handles it like a graphic object. It should be enough to delete the graphical representation, which you can do by changing it to display as an icon instead of a button.

For example, for an InlineShape:

```
Sub DeleteActiveX()
  Dim ils As word.InlineShape

  Set ils = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1)
  ils.OLEFormat.DisplayAsIcon = True
  ils.Delete
End Sub
```

You just have to figure out how to identify the InlineShape or Shape. You could bookmark an InlineShape; a Shape has a Name property.

EDIT: Since according to subsequent information provided in Comments you have a Shape object, rather than an InlineShape, the following approach should work:

```
Dim shp As word.Shape

Set shp = ActiveDocument.Shapes("Shape Name") 'Index value can also be used
shp.Delete
```

Note that Word will automatically assign something to the `Shape.Name` property, but in the case of ActiveX controls these names can change for *apparently* no reason. So if you identify a control using its name instead of the index value it's much better to assign a name yourself, which Word will not change "on a whim".

1. Activate Design Mode.
2. Click on the control to select it
3. Go to the VB Editor window
4. Ctrl+G to put the focus in the "Immediate Window"
5. Type the following (substituting the name you want), then press Enter to execute:

   Selection.ShapeRange(1).Name = "Name to assign"
6. Use this `Name` in the code above

Comment: Yes it is an ActiveX button. The part of figuring out the number of the InlineShape is the problem now... I read in another post that InlineShapes are listed in Selection Panel, but even I access it the ActiveX button is not showed there... Is there another way to discover it?

Comment: I tried to assign the inlineShape as number 1: Set inlineShape = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1) but I get error 5941 "The requested members of colection does not exist"

Comment: Are you sure it's an InlineShape and not a Shape? Graphically, is it formatted with text wrap or as inline? It's not in a Header, Footer or anything else by any chance?

Comment: In Wrap Text it is set as In Front Of Text

Comment: No, it isn't in header or in footer

Comment: Then it's a Shape, not an InlineShape.

Comment: I just edited my question, with the code returned when I recorded a macro. But even the macro doesn't work...

Comment: No, of course it doesn't work because, as I state, you can't run code when Design Mode is activated. See my edited response.

Comment: Man, you're great! After following your answer the code runs fine! The only thing I did was substitute the name  for "Control 52" from the recorded Macro (as you said, MS Word changed the name to "Control 52"), because this document is shared with others in my office, they don't need to know to go in Visual Basic and to assign the name to this commandButton

Comment: The only thing is the document doesn't retain the VBA Code (I'm working in a Macro Template Document), and the documents based on this template shows the Button but doesn't have any code. Is there something I can do to have a Template and the other users in my office create documents and run the code?